# Sorting algorithm works for C-array but not works for std::span

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, outofrangeexception

This problem happens when I am working on a insertion_sort algorithm.
I tried to implement a version for C++20's std::span but it throws a **"std::span index out of range"** So I turned it to **"C-array"** the same code works fine.
I don't know where is the problem. **P.S My platform is windows10 and I'm using VisualStudio2022**

This is the std::span version.

```cpp
template <typename Ty>
void insertion_sort(std::span<Ty> arr) {
    long long size = arr.size();
    // From the 2nd element to the nth element
    for (long long i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        Ty key = arr[i];
        long long j = i - 1;
        // Until the first element.
        for (; arr[j] > key && j >= 0; --j)
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        // Place key into the right position.
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

However if I change std::span to **C-array, like below, it works fine.**

```cpp
template <typename Ty>
void insertion_sort(Ty* arr, std::size_t size) {
    // From the 2nd element to the nth element
    for (long long i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        Ty key = arr[i];
        long long j = i - 1;
        // Until the first element.
        for (; arr[j] > key && j >= 0; --j)
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        // Place key into the right position.
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

I'll be glad if someone can help me fix this problem!

Comment: Just reverse the order of the conditions.

Comment: Btw: It should be pretty easy to determine more info about this kind of issue using a debugger. By default VS should break on uncaught exceptions and even if you catch the exception you can still tell the debugger to break when specific types of exceptions are thrown. This would have allowed you to determine that the value passed is something much too large and going up the stack find out that the reason is a conversion of `-1` to an unsigned type...

Comment: In general I'd recommend always running your program with a debugger attached  at least once regardless of whether the program seems to be working or not, since MSVC is able to identify some sources of UB this way...

Comment: This is an example why range-based `for` and `std::ranges` should be prefered over old school `for`.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in the for loop

```
    for (; arr[j] > key && j >= 0; --j)
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
```

is wrong. You need to exchange the operands of the logical AND operator

```
    for (; j >= 0 && arr[j] > key; --j)
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
```

Otherwise the index of the expression `arr[j]` can be equal to `-1`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. You did me a great favour!